# null pointer exception getting blob into listview imageview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, arrays, blob

i have column that is populated with byte[] aka image. I want to take that image and add it to my listview depending on my row... I have an XML file that has 2 textViews and an imageView, and here is my attempt at the code to get the image into the imageView..

```
public class CBFilter extends ListActivity {

ListView RecipeNames;
Cursor cursor, cursor2;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
CBDataBaseHelper data;
SQLiteDatabase data2;
TextView RecipeText, RowId;
String[] from = { CBDataBaseHelper.KEY_NAME };
int[] to = { R.id.row};
ImageView image;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
boolean diditwork;
try{
RecipeNames = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
RecipeNames.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.RecipeImage);
/* image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(dataImage, 0, dataImage.length));*/

RecipeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recipeText);
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, 0, cursor, null, null);
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.RecipeImage);
data = new CBDataBaseHelper(this);

data.open();
cursor = data.query();
startManagingCursor(cursor);
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
RecipeNames.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

byte[] blob=cursor.getBlob(4);
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob,0,blob.length);
image=new ImageView(this);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);


}catch(Exception e){
    diditwork = false;
    String error = e.toString();
    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setTitle("darn");
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(error);
    d.setContentView(tv);
    d.show();
}}


public void CreateNew(View view){

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, CBCreate.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(parent, v, position, id);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, CBCreate.class);
    long rowId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(CBDataBaseHelper.KEY_ROWID));
    String s = String.valueOf(rowId);
    intent1.putExtra("SELECTED", s);
    startActivity(intent1);
}





}


}
```

ok so this is my DBHelper class, call the method query()...

```
public class CBDataBaseHelper {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "Recipe_Name";
public static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "Recipe_Category";
public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "Recipe_Description";
public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "Recipe_Image";

public static final String KEY_ROWID2 = "_id";
public static final String fKEY_ROWID2 = "f_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME2 = "Ingredient_Name";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Recipedb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "RecipeData";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = "IngredientData";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DBHelper myHelper;
private final Context mycontext;
private SQLiteDatabase mydatabase;

private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "( " + KEY_ROWID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CATEGORY + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB" + ") ");



        /*db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE2 + "( " + KEY_ROWID2
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME2
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + fKEY_ROWID2 + " INTEGER , FOREIGN KEY " 
                + "(" + fKEY_ROWID2 + ") " + "REFERENCES " + DATABASE_TABLE 
                + "( " +  KEY_ROWID + " ))");*/



        db.execSQL("create table "
        + DATABASE_TABLE2 + " (" + KEY_ROWID2
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + KEY_NAME2
        + " text not null, " + fKEY_ROWID2 + " integer,"
+ " FOREIGN KEY ("+fKEY_ROWID2+") REFERENCES "+DATABASE_TABLE+" ("+KEY_ROWID+"));");

        /*db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE2 + "( " 
        + KEY_ROWID2 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_NAME2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, "  
        + fKEY_ROWID2 + " INTEGER , FOREIGN KEY " + "(" + fKEY_ROWID2 + ") " + "REFERENCES " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " +  KEY_ROWID + " ))");
    */
    }





    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL("DROP IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE2);
        onCreate(db);

    }
}

public CBDataBaseHelper(Context c){
    mycontext = c;

}

public CBDataBaseHelper open() throws SQLException{
    myHelper = new DBHelper(mycontext);
    mydatabase = myHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    myHelper.close();
}


public long createEntry(String name, String description, String category){

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    cv.put(KEY_CATEGORY, description);
    cv.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, category);
    return mydatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}

public long createEntry2(String name, Long fId){

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME2, name);
    cv.put(fKEY_ROWID2, fId);
    return mydatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, cv);

}

public Cursor query() {
    // Open Database

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_CATEGORY, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_IMAGE};
    Cursor cursor = mydatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null); 
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return cursor;


  }


public Cursor IngredientfetchRows(long frowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = mydatabase.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE2, new String[] { KEY_ROWID2, KEY_NAME2,
            fKEY_ROWID2 }, fKEY_ROWID2 + "="
            + frowId, null, null, null, null, null);

    return mCursor;

}


public Cursor IngredientfetchRow(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = mydatabase.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE2, new String[] { KEY_ROWID2, KEY_NAME2,
            fKEY_ROWID2 }, KEY_ROWID2 + "="
            + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}
public Cursor fetchRow(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = mydatabase.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
            KEY_CATEGORY, KEY_DESCRIPTION }, KEY_ROWID + "="
            + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}


 public boolean updateRecipe(long rowId, String RecipeName, 
         String RecipeCategory, String RecipeDescription) 
            {
                ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
                args.put(KEY_NAME, RecipeName);
                args.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, RecipeDescription);
                args.put(KEY_CATEGORY, RecipeCategory);

                return mydatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                                 KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
            }



 public boolean updateRecipe2(long rowId, String IngredientName) 
            {
                ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
                args.put(KEY_NAME2, IngredientName);

                return mydatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE2, args, 
                                 KEY_ROWID2 + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
            }


 public boolean updateRecipe3(long rowId, byte[] path) 
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_IMAGE, path);

        return mydatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                         KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

}
```

then i have the camera api which is saving the byte information to the column RecipeImage..

```
public class CameraAPI extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

public Camera camera;
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
CBDataBaseHelper RH;
TextView RecipeID;

public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    boolean diditwork;
    try{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);

    RecipeID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Rid2);
    String RowID;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();    
    RowID = extras.getString("SELECTED2");
    RecipeID.setText(RowID);
    SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.acccam);
    SurfaceHolder holder = surface.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}catch(Exception e){
    diditwork = false;
    String error = e.toString();
    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setTitle("darn");
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(error);
    d.setContentView(tv);
    d.show();
}}

        public void takePhoto(View view){
            //String ID = RecipeID.getText().toString();
            //Long LID = Long.parseLong(ID);
            boolean diditwork;
            try{
            takePicture();
            }catch(Exception e){
                diditwork = false;
                String error = e.toString();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("darn");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }
            //String path = "/sdcard/Image.jpg";
            //RH.updateRecipe3(LID,path);

    }




public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (mediaRecorder == null){
        try{
            camera = camera.open();
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.startPreview();

        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}



public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
}

public void takePicture(){
boolean diditwork;
    try{
    camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
    }catch(Exception e){
        diditwork = false;
        String error = e.toString();
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("darn");
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(error);
        d.setContentView(tv);
        d.show();
    }
}


ShutterCallback shutterCallback= new ShutterCallback()
{
    public void onShutter(){

    }
};

    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback(){
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){

        }
    };

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback(){
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;

            try{
                outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Image.jpg");
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
            }catch(IOException e){
                Log.d("CAMERA",e.getMessage());
            }
                RH = new CBDataBaseHelper(CameraAPI.this);
                RH.open();
                String ID = RecipeID.getText().toString();
                Long RID = Long.parseLong(ID);
                RH.updateRecipe3(RID, data);
                RH.close();

            }







};
}
```

the error that I am getting is a null point exception when i try to get the byte array to blob, any help here guys?

thanks

Stefan

Comment: It would help if you can post the logcat output of the error, so we can trace the origin of the exception

Comment: sorry i'm pretty new to this.. um i managed to fix the issue only to run into another issue... p.s does the code look correct? i mean for get blob to imageview?

Comment: you are querying the cursor after it's initialization, so I see a potential problem there...

Comment: yea i resolved this issue, it seems to be running alright now but there is no image within the image view... i shall edit the above code to what i have now if u need anymore info let me know

Comment: try setting all the code that looks like this `image=new ImageView(this);` to something like this: `image=new ImageView(CBFilter.this);` so the references are all correct, I also need to see how you're getting the data, the method in the DatabaseHelper that fetches the data, maybe there's the problem

Comment: ok so ive added the code again to show you the flow through each class.. ive notice that in my listview the from and to does not contain the imageView.. i dont know how to do this however as it expects a string for from

Comment: I see you are saving the image to SD and saving it again to the database, you should save the location of the image in the database, and then with the location of the image open an input stream and load the image from the SD card, it's easier and a recommended practice

Comment: hmmm, how would that method work for linking a photo with a particular row.. and also how would that work for multiple photo's, will the photo not be overwritten every time?

Comment: it would work exactly the same way, you just don't save the picture in the database, and instead of loading the picture from a byte array, you just use a FileInputStream not an OutputStream, so the photo won't be overwritten